# An inequality with $a,b,c>0$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$. Prove that:
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\leq\left(1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{b+c\sqrt{2}+a\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{c+a\sqrt{2}+b\sqrt{3}}\right)$$

Comment: The sign is reversed.

Comment: Where did you find this question - it is certainly wrong.  For e.g. $(a, b, c) = (0.1, 0.1, 2.8)$ gives $LHS \approx 20.36 > RHS \approx 3.13$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will suffice to show that the following (stronger) inequality holds
for positive $a,b,c,u,v,w$ :

$$
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \geq
(u+v+w)\bigg(\frac{1}{au+bv+cw}+\frac{1}{av+bw+cu}+\frac{1}{aw+bu+cv}\bigg)
$$

The fonction $f : x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$, so

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
f(\frac{u}{u+v+w}a+\frac{v}{u+v+w}b+\frac{w}{u+v+w}c) &\leq& \frac{u}{u+v+w}f(a)+\frac{v}{u+v+w}f(b)+\frac{w}{u+v+w}f(c) \\
f(\frac{v}{u+v+w}a+\frac{w}{u+v+w}b+\frac{u}{u+v+w}c) &\leq& \frac{v}{u+v+w}f(a)+\frac{w}{u+v+w}f(b)+\frac{u}{u+v+w}f(c) \\
f(\frac{w}{u+v+w}a+\frac{u}{u+v+w}b+\frac{v}{u+v+w}c) &\leq& \frac{w}{u+v+w}f(a)+\frac{u}{u+v+w}f(b)+\frac{v}{u+v+w}f(c) \\
\end{array}
$$

Adding up, we obtain the desired inequality.